# How to change the desktop background according to the time with python?

Tags: python-3.x, windows

So I have this code which changes the background according to the local time. The problem is that once the code is run it stops, but I want it to keep checking forever until the time has changed. So is there a way to add like a while loop or any kind of for loop. Also, how would you add this python file to a task in windows so it runs forever?

The code:

```
import ctypes
import time

dawn_wallpaper = "C:/Users/meena/Downloads/Backgrounds/Mac_Dawn.jpg"
sunrise_wallpaper = "C:/Users/meena/Downloads/Backgrounds/Mac_Sunrise.jpg"
mid_day_wallpaper = "C:/Users/meena/Downloads/Backgrounds/Mac_MidDay.jpg"
dusk_wallpaper = "C:/Users/meena/Downloads/Backgrounds/Mac_Dusk.jpg"
night_wallpaper = "C:/Users/meena/Downloads/Backgrounds/Mac_Night.jpg"
midnight_wallpaper = "C:/Users/meena/Downloads/Backgrounds/Mac_Midnight.jpg"

result = time.localtime()
hours = result.tm_hour

if 3 <= hours <= 5:
   user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True).SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, dawn_wallpaper, 0)
elif 6 <= hours <= 11:
   ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, sunrise_wallpaper, 0)
elif 12 <= hours <= 17:
   ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, mid_day_wallpaper, 0)
elif 18 <= hours <= 20:
   ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, dusk_wallpaper, 0)
elif 21 <= hours <= 22:
   ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, night_wallpaper, 0)
elif 23 <= hours <= 2:
   ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, midnight_wallpaper, 0)
```

Comment: You can use _Task Scheduler_ option present in the windows , let it run for every one hour or whatever time you want.If it runs ,it will automatically change the background according to the time you specified in the code

Comment: How am I supposed to do that? Do I have to import the python file?

Comment: [https://datatofish.com/python-script-windows-scheduler/ ]  Refer that how to setup that process